# Providing Alternative Resources

Tags: android

I have default folder `values` for my `dimens.xml`. Now it happens that I need to use some other value for `mdpi` devices. In order to achieve this I have to specify alternative resource, namely `values-mdpi\dimens.xml`. But as soon as I do it I must define `values-xhdpi`, `values-hdpi`, etc, to show proper sizes for screens of different densities. So basically in order to define the only value for `mdpi` devices I need to create **several** different files. Is there any easy way to define value for `mdpi` and that's it?

Comment: As far as I know, if Android doesn't find a resource for a specific density, it will take that resource from a folder with a higher or lower density. So you can create just 2 files: mdpi and hdpi, other densities will use the closest value.

Comment: just define you mdpi value in values/dimens.xml, and set another values in values-hdpi/dimens.xml
. The mdpi devices will use values/dimens.xml.  
The hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi devices will use values-hdpi/dimens.xml

Answer (score 1):

I'm relatively new to android but I'm pretty sure that if you don't specify the resource for any other sizes the value in the default values directory will be used.

See the android documentation page on both supporting multiple screens and how the correct resource is determined.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

Comment: But the point is to specify an alternative resource, if I use the only default one I don't get what I need.

Comment: Correct, I'm not sure if I properly conveyed this by the assumption that once you specify resources for mdpi you don't necessarily have to specify the resources for the other sizes (hdpi, xhdpi, etc.) as they should still take the values from the default folder.  Unless of course you can't specify a general value for that dimension, then I don't think there's really anyway around it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a solution.

If you use maven to build your application, you can make a folder with name eg. `yourproject-res` in the same place where `res` folder is. Then you can put anything you want to this folder (like `drawable` folder, `layout` folder, `drawable-mdpi` folder, `values` folder etc.).
After that you need to modify your pom.xml to create second profile of your application, like:

```
    <profile>
        <id>yourprojectmdpi</id>            
        <properties>
            <package.name>.com.your.app</package.name>
            <res.directory>yourproject-res</res.directory>      
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

And then the last step is to clean install your application with maven using `-P` parameter to point on your defined profile.

`mvn clean install -Pyourprojectmdpi`

and then

`mvn android:deploy android:run` to send apk from `target` folder to your device and run.

[Here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), [here](http://blog.akquinet.de/2011/01/14/starting-android-application-development-with-apache-maven/) and [here](http://www.manydesigns.com/en/portofino/portofino3/tutorials/using-maven-profiles-and-resource-filtering) you have a reference to maven profiles.

I hope I correctly understood your problem.